# C# datagridview double click event wont trigger

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

i have 2 forms, form1 has datagridview that contain data from my database.

everytime i click a cell on that datagridview, form2 show up,

after i click Edit_button on form2, form2 close and form1 show up

the problem is after form1 show up, the doubleclick event wont trigger again
here is my code :

form1

```
private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.textBox1.text = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    this.Hide();
    if (form2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        this.Show();
        load_DGV();
    }
}
```

form2

```
private void edit_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // EDIT METHOD

    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
}
```

if i'm not using load_DGV(), the doubleclick event still work, but i want to refresh my datagridview with newest data everytime form1 loaded.

sorry about my english anyway.

Comment: hard to follow, but FormLoad only runs the first time the form is made visible.  Hiding then Showing will not run FormLoad.

Comment: i think it is because i load new datagridview, not FormLoad, is there any way that i can "refresh" doubleclick event after i click Edit_button on form2 ?

Comment: Like I said, hard to follow.  `i want to refresh my datagridview with newest data everytime form1 loaded` form1 is loaded only once

Comment: What exactly does load_DGV do? Can you show the code?

Comment: it is just a code that i use to fill my datagridview with a table from my mysql database, do you really want me to post the code?

Comment: Posting the code could help.  For example, if you are saying `dataGridView1 = new DataGridView()` in that method, then yes, you are losing your event handler.  In which case see the answer provided by @meica or don't new the dgv up.

Answer (score 0):

Without the load_DGV the code is definitely working. So if you say "i load new datagridview" make sure to have something like this to set the doubleClick Event:

```
this.dataGridView1.CellDoubleClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick);
```

But it would be better if you post the code of load_DGV() because there must be the mistake.